# Complex function with property: $f(z+w) = f(z) + f(w)$.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

If $f$ is a complex vauled fuction which in analytic in the complex plane and  satisfies,

$ f(z+w) = f(z) + f(w) ,    z, w  $ are complex  numbers

Then  show that  $ f(z) = cz$     where $c$ is a constant..

I have tried to break the function in real and imaginary part. But failed to solve.
Any help is highly appreciated .

Comment: $f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$ which implies that $f(0)=0$, then you have only to show that the second derivative with respect to z is zero

Comment: $f(z)=z+1$ does not satisfy the hypothesis. As a further hint, try computing the derivative of f at some point.

Comment: You [vandalized your own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4016398/6) by completely rewriting it. Do not do that.  I rolled it back to rectify the situaton.

Comment: But they are not providing  me any chance  of asking  questions. Then what can I do?

Comment: @Jaymaa Who is "they" and what do you mean you can't ask questions?

Comment: I have  post some problems  which are  highly downvoted. So they are not giving me the chance  to ask.

Comment: @Jaymaa When I look at your history I do see a couple of posts with downvotes, but that alone would not cause you problems. It is probably the case that you also have some deleted posts that I cannot see that are contributing to an automatic system limit on your questions.

Comment: @Jaymaa I would advise reading the advice given with the ban and following it, and a little patience.  Definitely stop trying to circumvent it by vandalizing your own questions. Circumventing moderation is a great way to get yourself on the fast track to a suspension.  This sometimes happens to new users before they figure out how to post well. It seems like in most cases after this sort of thing has been resolved, users do not get stuck again.

Comment: What should ibdo ,please  help me friend.I am new here.I have questions  but can not ask any more

Comment: @Jaymaa Do as the notification asks: that's the only help I can offer at the moment.

Comment: Good bye my friend

Comment: I am deleting my account

Answer (score 1):

Substituting into the equation
$$
f(z+w)=f(z)+f(w)\tag1
$$
$z=w=0$ one obtains
$$
f(0)=0.\tag2
$$

Since the function is analytic in the whole complex plane its derivative exists everywhere and is constant:

$$
f'(z)=\lim_{\Delta z\to0}\frac{f(z+\Delta z)-f(z)}{\Delta z}\stackrel{(1)}=\lim_{\Delta z\to0}\frac{f(\Delta z)}{\Delta z}=c,\tag3
$$
which after combining with (2) gives
$$
f(z)=cz.
$$

Comment: Everything is done ,but i don't understand that why the derivative is c??

Comment: @Jaymaa If the value of a function does not depend on the value of  argument, the function is constant. I chose for the constant the name "$c $".

Comment: How  you know that the value of the  function is not dependent in its argument??

Comment: @Jaymaa Because the value of $z $ is absent in the expression $$\lim_{\Delta z\to0}\frac{f(\Delta z)}{\Delta z}.$$

Comment: please understand my query. I am asking  why it is independent  of the argument? You just tell me why why applying limit the result is just onky a constant?

Comment: @Jaymaa It is not because of applying the limit. It is because the dependence on $z $ has cancelled due to the property (1). I especially marked the appropriate equality sign in (3) to clarify the reason for the equation.